# Is there a more efficient way to compare 3+ items in an If statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am writing a program for a class assignment and I want to compare multiple items in an array for equivalence. My statement basically looks like:

```
if (a == b && b == c && c == d && d == e && e == f) {
   // do stuff
}
```

This condition seems incredibly verbose, and I am wondering if there's a shorter way to write this.

Comment: Do you want to compare that all elements are equal or what is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: If they're in an array, I suggest you create a separate method to compare them all. What's the element type? And what would you want to happen if the array is empty?

Comment: Make a set: `public <T> Set<T> GetSetFromArray(T[] array) { return new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(array)); }`  then call `if (GetSetFromArray(T[]{a, b, c,d}).size() == 1){}`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That's overkill.

Comment: I want to compare multiple elements (int specifically) in an array to see if they're equivalent. I guess creating a separate method would be best, since it will reduce a lot of clutter. As for the array being empty, I think I can assume that the array won't be empty for the sake of the assignment.

Comment: @PabloLozano It is just a suggestion I did not use Java since more than 10 years. Other wise I had posted an answer instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't use Java since for long time, Is my code u( posted an answer)sing set is O(1) in Java (I am applying Python concept here).

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Creating the set isn't O(1) to start with. Checking it afterwards is, but that's a different matter.

Answer (score 3):

This may appear to be *verbose*, but at least it is reasonably efficient and *clear*.

Don't overdo it with optimizing code for brevity.

You could easily make a helper function

```
boolean allEqual(Object ... objs) {
    for(int i = 1; i < obj.length; i++) {
      if (!objs[i].equals(objs[0])) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
}
```

But this will create additional objects; in particular with primitive values:

```
if (allEqual(1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1))
```

will create 5 objects, that need to be garbage collected.

Make sure you actually want `==` and not `equals`.

Comment: He said the elements are currently in an array, so your method could receive it directly that array, avoiding creating new objects.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to create a set and if its size is one then all elements are equal, otherwise not:

```
public static < E > boolean areAllEqual( E[] inputArray ){
    Set<E> mySet = new HashSet<E>(Arrays.asList(inputArray));
    return mySet.size() == 1;
}
```

Following is complete code example:

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{
    public static < E > boolean areAllEqual( E[] inputArray ){
        Set<E> mySet = new HashSet<E>(Arrays.asList(inputArray));
        return mySet.size() == 1;
    }    
     public static void main(String []args){
        Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        Double[] doubleArray = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
        Character[] charArray = { 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H' };

        System.out.println("It should work");
        if (areAllEqual(intArray))
            System.out.println("inarray Yes");
        else
            System.out.println("inarray No");

        if (areAllEqual(doubleArray))
            System.out.println("doubleArray Yes");
        else
            System.out.println("doubleArray No");

        if(areAllEqual(charArray))
            System.out.println("charArray  Yes");
        else
            System.out.println("charArray  No");                            
     }
}
```

output:

```
It should work
inarray No
doubleArray No
charArray  Yes  // all elements in char array are eq
```

Comment: I like this approach, I tend to use collections for things like that for several reasons - Readability, stability and efficiency. Side note: I recommend using `{` and `}` after `if` statements even if the body only contains one line.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Can we do something like `int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, e = 1;`  then `if(areAllEqual(int[]({a, b, c, d, e})))`?  Like I can use compound literals in C99 `(int []){2, 4}` e.g. [here](http://ideone.com/HpcLv5)

Comment: OK can be called like `if (areAllEqual(new Integer[] { a, b, c, d, e }))`

Answer (score 1):

This could be done in Java 8 the following, given that you already have an array:

```
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
if (Arrays.stream(numbers).allMatch(i -> (i == numbers[0]))) {
    //they are equal
}
```

What it does is:

- It encapsulates your array in an `IntStream` (it does **not** create extra objects, apart from the `IntStream`)
- It checks if all objects return true on the `IntPredicate`.
- The `IntPredicate` is `i -> (i == numbers[0])`, which maps `i` to `(i == numbers[0])`.

It would be advised to encapsulate this in a helper method, and you'd want to early bail if the array is empty, like this:

```
public static boolean allEquals(final int[] input) {
    return (input.length > 0 && Arrays.stream(input).allMatch(i -> i == input[0]));
}
```

This depends though on whether it should return `true` or `false` if there's no input... Is everything equal then?

Please note that you'd need to make this code for all primitives you are using. As an extra, you can also provide a generic version:

```
public static <T> boolean allEquals(final T[] input) {
    return (input.length > 0 && Arrays.stream(input).allMatch(i -> i.equals(input[0])));
}
```

Now when you do not have a suitable structure, meaning they are most likely just variables, then **you** will need to decide whether you are needing the extra performance or can live with the overhead of passing them in as an *varargs* input, that implicitely creates an array, the code for that would be really similar:

```
public static <T> boolean allEquals(final T... input) {
    return (input.length > 0 && Arrays.stream(input).allMatch(i -> i.equals(input[0])));
}
```

You can almost certainly live with the extra overhead, only in very performance critical applications, you need to wary if your method gets executed a load of times.